# How can I use directives to set the locale attribute of p-calendar in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, primeng

I have a very large application with hundreds of primeng p-calendar components in it. Now I need to set the locale in all of them. Directives seem to be a good option but I'm unable to use them for some reason. The following code does not work in my directive -

```
appConsts=ApplicationConstants
constructor(el:ElementRef) {
el.nativeElement.locale=this.appConsts.en;
}
```

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Add this directive to your project and change the locale property values to use the desired language.

```js
import { Directive, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLocale]'
})
export class PCalendarLocalDirective {
  // This is the correct way but it is not working for now, use this after the bug fixed.
  // @HostBinding('locale')
  locale = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 0,
    dayNames: ['ראשון', 'שני', 'שלישי', 'רביעי', 'חמישי', 'שישי', 'שבת'],
    dayNamesShort: ['ראש\'', 'שני', 'שלי\'', 'רבי\'', 'חמי\'', 'שיש\'', 'שבת'],
    dayNamesMin: ['א\'', 'ב\'', 'ג\'', 'ד\'', 'ה\'', 'ו\'', 'ש\''],
    monthNames: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני', 'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'נובמבר', 'דצמבר'],
    monthNamesShort: ['ינו\'', 'פבר\'', 'מרץ', 'אפר\'', 'מאי', 'יוני', 'יולי', 'אוג\'', 'ספט\'', 'אוק\'', 'נוב\'', 'דצמ\''],
    today: 'היום',
    clear: 'נקה'
  };

  // This way, injecting the component by @Host, is a workaround, this is an open issue in angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13776
  constructor(@Host() private pCalendar: Calendar) {
    pCalendar.locale = this.locale;
  }

}
```

Then, add the directive to all p-calendar in your project:

```html
<p-calendar appLocale></p-calendar>
```

NOTE: notice that there is an [open bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13776) in angular's git repo. could be the reason you couldn't get this to work.